# Is there any integer solutions of $3x^3+3x+7=y^3$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$3x^3+3x+7=y^3$

$x, y \in \mathbb{N}$

Having thought about it two hours, and I'm still not sure how to show there actually aren't any integer solutions.

EDIT
Another formulation of this problem: Prove that $3x^3+3x+7$ cannot be a perfect cube.

Comment: It was in a math competition for highschool students in Russia today.

Comment: I've talked to at least 20 very smart students, and nobody can solve this equation.

Comment: Numerically it's easy to check that there are no solutions for $x<10^5$ so you should be looking to prove that no solutions can exist.

Comment: Winther, I've already checked it in Wolfram Mathematica.

Comment: Note that if $x$ is positive then $\frac yx$ is an approximation to $\sqrt [3] 3$ - maybe worth examining rational approximations?

Comment: I did not have much luck solving it, but I found a factorization that might be useful: $3(x+1)(x^2 - x + 2) = (y-1)(y^2 + y + 1)$

Comment: I didn't come too far, but it would be equivalent to finding x and s such that $x^3+x+2 = 9s^3+3s^2+s$

Comment: For the most general approach, write the equation in elliptic curve form and apply elliptic curve methods. For this specific equation there might be an easy way (if this question was put on a high school math contest I don't see why not). A quick scan reveals $(-1, 1)$ to be a point. Thue-Siegel-Roth tells us there are a finite number of integer points. I don't know if there is an algorithm to find all of them... one could look up the equation in an online database of elliptic curves?

Answer (score 2):

There are no natural solutions for $x$ and $y$.

A quick bit of important information: If $C_n$ is the $n$th non-negative cube ($0,1,8,...$), then $C_{n+1}-C_n = 3n^2+3n+1$. (This can be grasped visually by a similar method to the visual proof that the consecutive differences of consecutive squares are consecutive odd integers.)

Let $s,a$ be positive integers such that $a=s-1$ (this will make the math a bit easier later).

$y$ is clearly greater than $x$ so let $y=x+s=x+a+1$.

Subtract $x^3$ from both sides of $3x^3+3x+7=y^3$ to get $$2x^3+3x+7=y^3-x^3$$

Let us focus on expanding $y^3-x^3$. Note that this is equivalent to $$((x+a+1)^3-(x+a)^3)+((x+a)^3-(x+a-1)^3)+\cdots+((x+2)^3-(x+1)^3)+((x+1)^3-x^3)$$ Which, by expanding the differences of consecutive cubes, is equivalent to: $$3x^2+3x+1+3(x+1)^2+3(x+1)+1+3(x+2)^2+3(x+2)+1+⋯+3(x+a)^2+3(x+a)+1=$$ $$3(x^2+x+(x+1)^2+x+1+\cdots+(x+a)^2+x+a)+a+1=$$ $$3(x^2+(x+1)^2+⋯+(x+a)^2)+3(x+x+1+⋯+x+a)+a+1$$

Note $a+1$ arises since $1$ appears $a+1$ times in the expression.

We now condense the first two terms on the RHS (starting with the first): $$3(x^2+(x+1)^2+⋯+(x+a)^2)=$$ $$3(x^2+x^2+2x+1+x^2+4x+4+x^2+6x+9+⋯x^2+2ax+a^2)=$$ $$3(x^2(a+1)+xa(a+1)+\frac{a(a+1)(2a+1)}{6})$$

These coefficients are obtained by noting there are $a+1$ terms of $x^2$ (as above with $1$s), that the coefficients on the $x$ terms are the first $a$ even integers, and that the constants are the first $a$ squares.

Now we move to the second term on the RHS:

$$3(x+x+1+⋯+x+a)=$$ $$3(x(a+1)+\frac{a(a+1)}{2})$$

Again, the coefficients are found by noting the $a+1$ $x$ terms and the first $a$ positive integers.

Now, returning to $$3(x^2+(x+1)^2+⋯+(x+a)^2)+3(x+x+1+⋯+x+a)+a+1$$ we replace the first two terms with results found above to obtain: $$3(x^2(a+1)+xa(a+1)+\frac{a(a+1)(2a+1)}{6})+3(x(a+1)+\frac{a(a+1)}{2})+a+1$$

At this point it is convenient to substitute $a$ for $s-1$ which leaves us with: $$3(x^2s+xs(s-1)+\frac{s(s-1)(2s-1)}{6})+3(xs+\frac{s(s-1)}{2})+s$$

Distribute the $3$'s: $$3x^2s+3xs(s-1)+\frac{s(s-1)(2s-1)}{2}+3xs+\frac{3s(s-1)}{2}+s=$$ $$3x^2s+3xs^2+\frac{s(s-1)(2s-1)+3s(s-1)}{2}+s=$$ $$3x^2s+3xs^2+\frac{s(s-1)(2s+2)}{2}+3s=$$ $$3x^2s+3xs^2+s(s-1)(s+1)+s=$$ $$3x^2s+3xs^2+s^3$$

UPDATE This answer previously contained a mathematical error which has since been corrected, however as a result it no longer solves the problem.

Comment: I'm grateful for all the upvotes, but upon a second reading I think my answer contains an error, as it implies $y^3-x^3+x^3\neq y^3$. However I cannot find the error...

Comment: The very last term in line following "Distribute the $3$'s" looks suspicious; where did it get its $3$ from? ;-)

Comment: That would be it! Thanks!